# prometheus triggering false kafka active controller alert

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus-alertmanager

I have 3 node kafka and zookeeper setup, Kafka Active controller being monitored by Prometheus with the below matrix

```
sum by(component, service) (kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_value{name="ActiveControllerCount"}) != 1
```

The issue is some time Prometheus is triggering a false alert like no active controller but when I checked on the server through the zookeeper shell I got one of the brokers as an active controller.

when I am listing the active node time it is showing 2 Kafka nodes or 1 Kafka node not all the Kafka nodes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzEd5.png)

so if any point in time active controller Kafka node is not in the above list, alert triggers.
how to make sure all nodes should be listed above and Prometheus should not trigger false alerts.

no clue where and how to start.

Prometheus UI Targets list shows below.

context deadline exceeded